# What does .offsetX (0) in twitter bootstrap less means?

Tags: recursion, twitter-bootstrap, less

I had a look at twitter bootstrap mixin.less where they generate the grid. There's this line of code:

```
.offsetX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
  (~".offset@{index}") { .offset(@index); }
  .offsetX(@index - 1);
}
.offsetX (0) {}
```

Does anyone know what does that `.offsetX (0)` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.offsetX (@index)` is recursive when the index is greater than 0, and iterates by subtraction, this case represents the terminal point of the recursive function.

If you set @index to 12, it will write `.offset12, .offset11,..., .offset1` and write nothing for `.offset0`.

### Edit

As the preprocessor attempts to resolve the mixin call for `.offsetX (0)`, the **when** keyword is going to guard against using the recursive mixin.  If another mixin isn't found, an error will result, sort of like calling an undefined function.

Hence, the terminating case of `.offset (0) {}` is there to cleanly exit the recursion.

If you'd like to play with it, here's a basic demo with which you can try commenting out the line with the terminal case, and then observe the exception on rerunning.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/HEseF/)

Comment: but why that line of code needs to be there? I mean it has been specified to only to execute the codes inside when `@index` is bigger than 0. Isn't that mean that when `@index` reach zero, it should terminate the recursion by itself?

Comment: @zen - I updated my answer. Hopefully that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: I class it as a minor bug.. dotless doesn't do it, but I havent changed less.js because noones complained or raised an issue.

Comment: @LukePage - For the record, **lessc** throws *"SyntaxError: No matching definition was found for '.offsetX()' in ..."*.

Comment: I know.. when it searches for mixin defintions it errors if it finds nothing matching.. dotless errors if it finds nothing matching the arguments, but if something is excluded because of a guard, it does not error.. that is what it might be nice for less.js to do. Then you don't need default fallbacks when using guards.

Comment: @merv - I've checked your code. Actually I have done test in my local as well. Normally I compile my less using `livereload`, and when I remove that line, it'll throw an error. Now I kind of understand the reason why that happens. But like @LukePage, I'd prefer to be able do it without default fallbacks..